Sample bezier curve based on curvature in geometry nodes
Here is a bezier curve from which I am generating some geometry in Geometry Nodes.

Region 1 and Region 3 have significantly different sample densities although they both have the same curvature.
More importantly, the extrusion happening around the sharp curve at 2 is failing because the sample density is too low.
How can I sample the bezier curve such that

there is an overall parameter for resolution (e.g. total number of points)
higher/lower curvature regions have appropriately higher/lower sample resolution


Do you try and compute the curvature using this proposal : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/315866/177431 ?

@StefLAncien suppose I compute the curvature with the method you suggest. Then what?

Here's a simulation that continuously removes points with the least angular change:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Imgur mirror
Angle Change is a custom group:

Imgur mirror
If you're not satisfied with the order of removed points, this is the node you may want to tinker with, e.g. add distance to the previous point to the calculation, maybe also multiply the distance by some amount, but keep in mind the effect will look differently based on the size of the spline. You could also calculate an area of a triangle formed by evaluated, previous and next points.
All that's left to do is to convert the simulation zone to a repeat zone, and set the number of iterations to the number of points you want to remove. If you want to add points, not just remove them, add a step before removing where you resample the curve. If you don't want to unnecessarily change the shape of the curve, consider converting to mesh, subdividing and converting back to curve.
You could parallelize the algorithm for performance by removing a repeat zone, or at least decreasing the number of iterations, and remove points in bulk, but then it will become unreliable because the algorithm is serial, not parallel, in nature.

